# print id one time PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code php/pdo and it works fine

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$place = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `category`=".$id."");
$place->execute();

foreach ($place->fetchAll() as $rawp){
   $mains = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `place` WHERE `id`=".$rawp['placeid']."");
   $mains->execute();

   foreach ($mains->fetchAll() as $rawps){
      echo $rawps['id'].'<br/>';
   }
}
```

and the result of that code like this

```
113
114
125
122
122
127
127
```

My question is: how can I print each place ID just once? I don't want duplicates like ID `122`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and print only once each unique number

```
$id = (int)$_GET['id'];
$place = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `category`=".$id."");
$place->execute(); 
$array = array();
foreach ($place->fetchAll() as $rawp){
$mains = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `place` WHERE `id`=".$rawp['placeid']."");
$mains->execute(); 
foreach ($mains->fetchAll() as $rawps){ 
    if(!in_array($rawps['id'], $array)){
        echo $rawps['id'].'<br/>';
    }
    $array[] = $rawps['id'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Edited it. Check now

Comment: Please don't create SQL statement strings by concatenating data from $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST! Use variable binding instead like in my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

SQL can do that for you with `DISTINCT`, you only need one SQL-Statement if you `JOIN` the two tables and you don't even have to `SELECT *` all columns but only the ones that you want:

```
$places = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT `place`.`id`
             FROM `post` JOIN `place` ON `post`.`placeid` = `place`.id
             WHERE `post`.`category`=:category");
$places->execute(array('category' => $_GET['id']));
foreach ($places->fetchAll() as $place) {
   echo $place['id'] . '<br />';
}
```

This solution is more performant than executing two statements and later reducing the data programmatically, and, most important, uses variable binding (the `:category`) part in the `WHERE` clause, which prevents SQL injection. You should never create SQL statement strings by concatenating data from $_GET, $_POST or $_REQUEST.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.id FROM post JOIN place ON post.placeid = place.i' at line 1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\myjob\Emad\brand.php:200 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\myjob\Emad\brand.php(200): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\myjob\Emad\brand.php on line 200

Comment: Pls try again, I added backticks around the table and column names, which maybe helps.

Comment: thank you so much brother I will used later 
sorry for bad english 
thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Create a temporary array, iterate through your existing array and  push the unique values into it and then iterate through the temporary array to echo out each unique value: see the following, but I swapped out the db related stuff and added the numbers in  as a n array - this now works. You just need to swap in your db specific variables and it should be good to go.

```
$rawps= array("113","114","125","122","122","127","127");
$tempArray=[];
foreach ($rawps as $rawp){   
   $item = $rawp;
    if(! in_array($item, $tempArray)){array_push($tempArray,$item);
        }
}
 foreach($tempArray as $arrayItem){echo "$arrayItem  <br/>";}
```

prints the following
113
114
125
122
127

```
//$tempArray conteins the following: Array ( [0] => 113 [1] => 114 [2] => 125 [3] => 122 [4] => 127 )
```

Comment: not working brother . he prints all the numbers like my problem

Comment: Hi - I  just edited my answer - I swapped out the db related stuff and added the numbers in  as a n array - this now works. You just need to swap in your db specific variables and it should be good to go.